# Mysql Query - JOIN statement

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join

I have two tables that I need to query on:

```
Fixtures
-----------
fixture_id
hometeam_id
awayteam_id
fixture_date


Teams
-----------
team_id
team_name
```

I need to pull the team name from both the `hometeam_id` and `awayteam_id`, I can fetch one using a left or inner join statement, but can't work out how to get both without using a substatement.

```
SELECT t.team_name,f.away_teamid,f.home_teamid 
FROM fixtures f
LEFT JOIN teams t 
ON (t.team_id = f.hometeam_id)
```

Just to summarise I need the two names of the teams in each fixture

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check our the SQL Union operator or do another join

Comment: See sample [demo here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39777/2)

Answer (score 0):

Join teams table twice in order to get names for home team and away team ,use inner join if your fixture table must contain associations for home team and away team but if there can be null either home or away then use left join

```
SELECT 
f.fixture_id,
t.team_name home_team,
t1.team_name away_team,
f.fixture_date
from fixtures f 
join teams t on (t.team_id = f.hometeam_id)
join teams t1 on (t1.team_id = f.away_teamid)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT home.team_name AS Home, away.team_name AS Away FROM Fixtures fix
INNER JOIN Teams away on away.team_id = fix.awayteam_id
INNER JOIN Teams home on home.team_id = fix.hometeam_id
```